# Recording app with video playback / remote solution

Tags: design, ipad, recording

I am trying to find a solution to record foley in my recording booth while seeing a looping QuickTime movie on my iPad.

Is there any app that would allow me to do this?

To avoid all the file handling and other issues, I have also looked into just remote controlling my DAW, but then I am missing video playback.

I also tried one “remote access” app thing (Air Display?)  that would mirror my desktop to the iPad (and therefore letting me see my DAW + video), but the video playback from my DAW was very stuttering and had low framerate that would not work for foley stuff where sync is important.

Or is an external monitor with a loooooonnng cable into my other room really my only option?

Any clever ideas out there?

I feel like I am missing an obvious solution...

Thanks so much.
Djaja

Answer (score 0):

I use Vloop for video playback: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cwgs-video-loop-presenter/id423787575?mt=8

AirDisplay works best when you link your Pro Tools computer and your iPad via an adhoc network. There are dozens of tutorials explaining how to set up such a network.

I don't know how many meters of monitorcable you need, but I think VGA cables work fine for about 20 meter or so (if I remember correctly)

Comment: thanks for those suggestions!
Regarding vloop: how would i keep that in sync with my daw?
ideally each loop would be treated like a new take or track.
id rather not have to manually edit and realign all the takes i created in sync to the videoloop.

Answer (score 0):

The [Auria](http://auriaapp.com/Products/auria) DAW app apparently has a sync video playback function with record... not sure about how well looping is supported. Also cool stuff like AAF/OMF import, but I haven't actually tried it yet.

Myself, I use Neyrinck's excellent [V-Control](http://www.neyrinck.com/v-control-pro) App to control my DAW over wifi... mind you I already have a video feed in the booth from my PT rig for ADR etc, but V-Control does a great job of allowing me to control PT from the booth. I'd suggest getting a "proper" video feed into your booth is a worthwhile investment if you're planning to do this on a fairly regular basis. As Micheal pointed out, high quality VGA cables (DON'T buy the cheap ones) will let you run quite far.

Answer (score 0):

I think the obvious solution is to hook up an external monitor. But the answer really depends on what you have more of, cash or time.

If you're trying to record foley, or anything dependent on sync for that matter, I wouldn't trust the refresh rate of the ipad via the various display mirroring or extending apps. As you experienced with airdisplay, it lags... a lot. Even when directly connecting via adhoc.

While a VGA cable would work, I envision you having to either move or disconnect one display from your system every time you need to record foley. If you have the cash, go get a [DV box](http://www.grassvalley.com/products/advc110) or [PCI-E card](http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity/models/). They're fairly inexpensive secondhand. With the analog video output you can run 100s of feet of cable and set up a proper display. Then you can just run one of the display mirroring/extending apps to control your Pro Tools through the adhoc network. For simple start/stop/cueing there's no need to plunk down $50 on V-Control Pro, just use airdisplay and drag your transport and marker window onto your ipad's screen. Cue yourself up with the next marker, punch the transport into record and roll.

Alternatively, if you have the time, you can burn off a copy of the video with beeps for your cues, load that video directly on the ipad through iTunes, then use the stock iOS Videos app to playback and just roll ProTools wild. Voice slate each TC before performance, record the beeps on mic and perform, then re-sync all your beeps when done. Should fall in sync just fine. For inspiration, check out [this Soundworks video on the Hunger Games around 4:25](http://soundworkscollection.com/videos/thehungergames).